# javascript--Add and Remove Item

Tags: javascript

This is a part of my form. I add two buttons:add and remove. When I click the "add" button, I want to add two inputs and they have different styles. Also, when I click the "remove" button, the last pair of the input(activity time and content) will be removed. How could I achieve these effects(I know it should be achieved with onclick event)? Thanks!

```
        <div class="pure-g" id="activity">

                <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-sm-3-24 l-box" >
                    <input id="activityTime"  type="time" required>
                </div>
                <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-sm-9-24 l-box" >
                    <textarea id="actContent" class="pure-u-23-24" rows="5" required></textarea>
                </div>



        </div>

        <input id="btn-remove" class="pure-button pure-button-primary pure-btn-right" type="button" value="Remove">
        <input id="btn-add" class="pure-button pure-button-primary pure-btn-right" type="button" value="Add">
```

**Update**
I tried the two solutions below, they slightly had some problems. So I used jQuery. Here is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#btn-add').click(function(){
    $('#activity').append('<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-sm-3-24 l-box" >'+
        '<input id="activityTime"  type="time" required>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-sm-9-24 l-box" >'+
        '<textarea id="actContent" class="pure-u-23-24" rows="5" required>'+
        '</textarea>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>');
});
$('#btn-remove').click(function(){
    var count=$('#activity').children().length;
    if(count>4){
        $("#activity > div").slice(-2).remove();
    }

});
});
```

Comment: jQuery will make this requirement exponentially easier.  I highly recommend you consider using jQuery.

Comment: implement onclick function. Have a look at this reference: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_events1

Comment: You want to achieve that without the onclick handler? This isn't possible - you need to do something when you click in the button and the only way to do that is through the onclick handler

Comment: @ThomasStringer would you look at my answer and show me your fiddle with jQuery which is "exponentially easier"? Personally I highly recommend removing jQuery from tasks like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the input pair into div of some class ("pair" here)

```
var input='<div class="pair"><div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-sm-3-24 l-box" ><input id="activityTime"  type="time" required></div><div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-sm-9-24 l-box" ><textarea id="actContent" class="pure-u-23-24" rows="5" required></textarea></div></div>';
```

And then attach `add()` to Add button and `rem()` to Remove button

```
var activity = document.getElementById("activity");

function add() {
    activity.innerHTML+= input;
}

function rem() {
    var pairs = activity.getElementsByClassName("pair");
    var len = pairs.length;
    if(len>0) activity.removeChild(pairs[len-1]);
}
```

See [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3fb5p776/).

Comment: Here's a problem. The browser pointed the variable input "Unexpected identifier", but in your jsfiddle, everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

1) Add id to the add/remove inputs, you'll need to touch nothing else in your HTML:

```
<input id="remove" class="..." type="button" value="Remove">
<input id="add" class="..." type="button" value="Add">
```

2) Here's the JavaScript:

```js
var activity = document.getElementById("activity"),
    add = document.getElementById("add"),
    remove = document.getElementById("remove");

add.onclick = function() {
    var newTime = document.createElement("div"),
        newTimeIn = document.createElement("input"),
        newActivity = document.createElement("div"),
        newActivityIn = document.createElement("textarea");
    newTime.class = "pure-u-1 pure-u-sm-3-24 l-box";
    newTimeIn.type = "time";
    newTimeIn.required = "required";
    newTime.appendChild(newTimeIn);
    activity.appendChild(newTime);
    newActivity.class = "pure-u-1 pure-u-sm-9-24 l-box";
    newActivityIn.class = "pure-u-23-24";
    newActivityIn.rows = "5";
    newActivityIn.required = "required";
    newActivity.appendChild(newActivityIn);
    activity.appendChild(newActivity);
}
    
remove.onclick = function() {
    activity.removeChild(activity.lastElementChild);
    activity.removeChild(activity.lastElementChild);
}
```

```html
<div class="pure-g" id="activity">
  <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-sm-3-24 l-box" >
    <input id="activityTime" type="time" required>
  </div>
  <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-sm-9-24 l-box" >
    <textarea id="actContent" class="pure-u-23-24" rows="5" required></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<input id="remove" class="pure-button pure-button-primary pure-btn-right" type="button" value="Remove">
<input id="add" class="pure-button pure-button-primary pure-btn-right" type="button" value="Add">
```

Comment: Thanks! But the my class "pure-u-1 pure-u-sm-3-24 l-box" can't be added to the div.

Comment: you can just remove that line